# Golang Ravendb giving wrong query result when using OrderBy

Tags: database, nosql, sql-order-by, ravendb

When making query with `OrderBy` it always query wrong result whereby repeating first document multiple times added to list.

```
q := session.Advanced().DocumentQueryAllOld(reflect.TypeOf(&models.List{}), "", "user", false)
        //q = q.WhereNotEquals("Doc.hh", "Tarzan")
        q = q.OrderBy("Docnn")
        q = q.Statistics(&statsRef)
        //q = q.Skip(0)
       //q = q.Take(6)
        q.ToList(&queryResult)
```

If no index before it will query right result but if existing index auto created by a different `OrderBy` value it will query wrong result